# Do all Windows have the English language included for localization?

Tags: windows

My English version of Windows didn't have French language (I had to download it).

Would a French version of Windows come with English? And if so, is English language universal and comes already available (without needing to download) on all other language versions of Windows?

Comment: @Ramhound thanks. I am trying to ensure some system commands (executed from a separate piece of software) return the same output regardless of language settings. Do you know if there's any way of achieving that?

Comment: If you have Windows Home you are limited in any case to a single language. "You can add languages and regional support to Windows 10 (except for Windows 10 Home Single Language and Windows 10 Home Country Specific editions), and Windows Server."

Comment: @DavidPostill - Only Windows 10 Single Language is limited to a single language.  Windows 10 Home and Windows 10 Professional can install any number of language packs.  Author doesn’t have a Single Language edition of Windows based on their description

Comment: @Ramhound My quote is direct from [Localize | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/localize-windows).

Comment: @DavidPostill - Yes; Your quote contracts your own statement.  **Windows 10 Home** is not **Windows 10 Home Single Language**. Your first sentence in your last comment says that **Windows 10 Home** can only install one language which simply isn’t true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would a French version of windows come with English?

No; a French Windows 10 Home ISO only contains the French language pack by default.  You can modify this image without much fanfare and add any language packs you might.

> Is English language universal and comes already available (without needing to download) on all other language versions of windows?

The English Windows 10 Home ISO only contains the English language pack by default.

> . I am trying to ensure some system commands (executed from a separate piece of software) return the same output regardless of language settings. Do you know if there's any way of achieving that?

Create your own Windows 10 Home image and use that to install Windows 10.